# How to convert each item of a list of strings into an empty list object with the string as list name?

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to convert each item of a list of strings into an empty list object with the string as list name.

Input:

```
list_items = ["string1","string2"]
```

Output: 2 empty lists called  "string1" and "string2

```
 print(string1) -> []
 print(string2) -> []
```

Thank you!

Comment: See the duplicate, but short answer: don't do that. Use a dict.

Comment: I think a default dict would do best for you

Answer (score 0):

Use local()

```
list_items = ["string1","string2"]
for l in list_items:
   locals()[l] = []

print(string1)
print(string2)
```

NB: there are strong arguments against this method but it will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: See the duplicate for recommended ways to do what the OP wants, but note that [the documentation for locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) explicitely states not to modify it: "Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."